# How do I calculate hours when there are fractional components

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a spreadsheet to calculate my hours for the week.  The problem I am having is the DateDiff function only returns integers so I am getting incorrect results.

```
Function CalculateHoursDay(strStart As String, strEnd As String, intLunch As Integer) As Double

    Dim dblHours As Double

    dblHours = DateDiff("h", strStart, DateAdd("h", 12, strEnd)) - intLunch

    CalculateHoursDay = dblHours

End Function
```

If I call the function with "7:00", "2:45", .5 then I get 7 back when I need 7.25.  In fact I get 7 also for "7:00", "2:45", 0 so you can see the decimal value is getting truncated.  I add 12 hours so times can be easily entered without regard for AM, PM or military time since over 99% (if not 100%) of the time the times will be AM for start time and PM for end time.

I am expecting to get 7.25 from the function with the stated parameters.  Any suggestions?

Comment: try dblHours = DateDiff("n", strStart, DateAdd("h", 12, strEnd)) to calculate by minute (or s for second) and convert back to hours

Comment: First and formost, you are using `Integer` for your intLunch and attempting to pass 0.5. That's going to become a 0. Change it to `Double`.

Comment: Thanks Alex!!!  That was what I needed.  I tried using 'm' but it didn't work since I forgot 'm' was for month.  You are correct tbur.  I just never got to that part of the code because the prior function was not usable in its current form.  Did I mention I hate Mondays?

Comment: @JohnMaher you're welcome.  If you're looking for a builtin function's syntax / usage, you can always select the word in the editor and press function key F1.

Answer (score 4):

Alex provided the correct answer and tbur also pointed out a bug that would've surfaced as soon as I applied Alex's solution.

```
Function CalculateHoursDay(strStart As String, strEnd As String, dblLunch As Double) As Double

    Dim dblHours As Double

    '"n" refers to minutes.
    dblHours = (DateDiff("n", strStart, DateAdd("h", 12, strEnd)) / 60) - dblLunch

    CalculateHoursDay = dblHours

End Function
```